# Passing values to a windows batch file through PHP

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I am trying to get a batch file to run with commands that I am passing it. For security reasons we execute our commandline calls through `WScript.Shell`

This is what my batch file looks like:

```
@echo off
pushd \\theServer\wwwroot\tuition\uploads\
pdftk PDF_Template.pdf fill_form %1 output %2 need_appearances
popd
```

I am then passing the vars to the bat file like so:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$WshShell->exec(getcwd().'\uploads\test.bat 1412194760.fdf output.pdf');
```

When I run the bat file from the server, everything works fine. However, not getting any results when it runs from php.

This example worked just fine when I had the full paths in there which I am trying to get rid of now using the code above.

```
$WshShell->exec('"pdftk" C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\tuition\\uploads\\Educational_Assistance_Request_Form_North_America.pdf fill_form C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\tuition\\uploads\\'.$fdf_file.' output C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\tuition\\uploads\\'.$newPDF.' need_appearances');
```

Can you see anything obvious I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

As a test I hard coded the values into the batch file:

```
pdftk Educational_Assistance_Request_Form_North_America.pdf fill_form 1412194760.fdf output output.pdf need_appearances
```

I then tried just running the file with both `run` and `execute`

```
$WshShell->run(getcwd().'\uploads\test.bat'); 
$WshShell->exec(getcwd().'\uploads\test.bat');
```

This test also failed.

Maybe its a permission error for shell running a batch file?

**FIX:**
So even though I was running the exec command in this location:

```
getcwd().'\uploads\test.bat
```

When I logged it, it was only running it in the `cwd` and ignored the uploads folder.

I changed the batch file to this and it now works fine:

```
pdftk uploads/Educational_Assistance_Request_Form_North_America.pdf fill_form uploads/%1 output uploads/%2 need_appearances
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the "run" command of the WshShell object instead. In any case, why do you have the pdftk command surrounded by double quotes"?

Comment: The last example was the one that was working that I am trying to get away from. Not sure why I used the double quotes but it worked just fine.